# jQuery tabs - content appearing outside the tab border

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

**UPDATE:** I need to use IE8.

I want to put some div's inside a jquery tab. The content is appearing but it's outside of the tab border:
[image]

I've tried removing the border with `#tabs {border: none}` which works but I'd rather the border be there.

This is the HTML for the page (Stripped down):

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <h2 class="demoHeaders">
        Codes</h2>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">GT2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">GT3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">GT4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="questionActions">
                    Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, bl
                </div>
                <!-------------------------------------------ADD CONTENT BELOW THIS LINE---------------------------------------->
                <!-----------------------------------------------Slide 1----------------------------------------------->
                <div class="content" id="slide1">
                    <div class="slideText">
                        <strong>Nam dui erat, auctor a</strong><br />
                        Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet
                        ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum
                        bibendum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            Phasellus
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            Nam dui erat,
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for the page (Stripped down):

```
#container 
{
    position:absolute;
    width:99%;
    height:93%
}

#questionActions 
{
    width:99%;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    color:white;
    background-color:#005293;
}
```

Comment: Code is on the way...

Comment: Code helps us to help you.. :) better post `css` and `html` and if you are using any plugin mention it.. :)

Comment: Looks like it could be float / position problem but we need to look at the code to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `position:absolute` from `#container`.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j80xsej5/1/)

Comment: Wow that definately helps. But it only put the first div inside the tab border

Comment: Yup, should have mentioned - I'm on stupid IE8. I cant even goto jsfiddle

Comment: @KieranQuinn, what version of jQuery? Take a [look at this page in IE8](http://www.tnghardware.com/delete/foo.html). It renders fine for me in IE8 emulation mode... I removed all superfluous CSS. Just view source if it works

Comment: Yeah it displays correctly... damned if I know why. I'll run some more scenarios using that code... thank you